Native Federation in angular 17
I'm working on a project in Angular 17 which will use the micro frontend concept, and we've decided to work with Native Federation.
I followed the official website's manual, and everything works correctly, but I'm encountering an error in the terminal. Can someone help me? I detail my code as follows:
project shell:
federation.manifest.json
{ "mfe1": "http://localhost:4201/remoteEntry.json"}

main.ts
initFederation('/assets/federation.manifest.json')
.catch(err => console.error(err))
.then(_ => import('./bootstrap'))
.catch(err => console.error(err));

app.routes.ts
export const routes: Routes = [
{path: '', component: FormExampleComponent},
{
path: 'flights',
loadComponent: () => loadRemoteModule('mfe1', './Component').then((m) => m.RequestGuarenteeComponent),
}
] ;

mfe1:
federation.config.js 
const { withNativeFederation, shareAll } = require('@angular-architects/native-federation/config');
module.exports = withNativeFederation({
name: 'mfe1',
exposes: {
'./Component': './src/app/main/guarentee-plataform/request-guarentee/request-guarentee.component.ts',
},
shared: {
...shareAll({ singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' }),
},
skip: [
'rxjs/ajax',
'rxjs/fetch',
'rxjs/testing',
'rxjs/webSocket',
// Add further packages you don't need at runtime
]
});


and I encounter this error in the terminal, even though it works correctly and doesn't generate any errors in the browser:
ERROR Error: unknown remote mfe1
at eval (f:/RodrigoTV/project/MicorFrontEnd-beco/main-shell/shellbeco/node_modules/@softarc/native-federation-runtime/fesm2022/softarc-native-federation-runtime.mjs:156:15)
at Generator.next ()

tiene menú contextual
remove that error message

Could you please show the mfe1 app.component, with the routing?

I have almost a similar repo here is
https://github.com/lkovari/microfrontend-with-native-feeration
It works well. I have another problem with it, about the deployment to github pages.

What Angular and Native Federation version are you using?

I am using Angular 17.3.1 and native-federation 17.1.7

When is this error in the console appear? when you serve the mfe1 or try to load the mfe1 throught the shell? can you provide some repro steps or a small poc to reproduce this error?

What port is your MFE pointing to? And is it served on that port at the time of this error?

I had the same problem, it worked for me when I deactivated site pre-rendering. I was at the beginning of creating the project so I just created a new one without site pre-rendering activated.
Hope that helps!
Update: Issue still arises when dynamic-host is outside of projects folder.

Angular CLI: 17.3.5
Node: 18.17.1
Package Manager: npm 10.5.2
OS: win32 x64
@angular-architects/native-federation: 17.1.7


I have the similar app, which works as we expected:
https://github.com/lkovari/microfrontend-with-native-feeration
I have another problem about how to deploy the micro frontend applications?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78321094/cloudflare-i-deployed-an-angular-micro-frontend-project-on-cloudflare-the-rout
