Cloudflare: I deployed an Angular micro frontend project on Cloudflare, the routing not working on any browsers at all
May I ask you to help me?
There is a deployed micro frontend angular v17 apps
https://b203a78a.microfrontend-with-native-feeration.pages.dev/
(it loaded slowly and did not found any page, but the Home is working after that)
The structure is:
workspace: micro-fe-workspace
apps:
-shell (main)
-microfrontend-a (remote)
-microfrontend-b (remote)
-library shared-lib
I use esbuild which deployed to appname/browser folder
Here is the dist folder structure:
dist/
shell
microfrontend-a
microfrontend-b
shared-lib
index.html
The build scripts:
"build:shared-lib": "ng build shared-lib --configuration production",
"toshared-lib": "cd dist/shared-lib",
"publishshared-lib": "npm publish --access=public",
"build-prod-b": "ng build microfrontend-b --configuration production",
"build-prod-a": "ng build microfrontend-a --configuration production",
"build-prod-s": "ng build shell --configuration production",
"postbuild": "cp indexd.html dist/index.html",
In the indexd.html:





Welcome

    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
    }
    div {
        width: 100%;
    }




    Welcome to the Micro frontend Angular app example.
Start
When I try to navigate on the page i faced with the following error:
_angular_core-17_3_3.js:5 ERROR Error: unknown remote microfrontendB at chunk-KBMX4XI6.js:1:2854 at Generator.next () at s (chunk-KBMX4XI6.js:1:480) at Z.invoke (polyfills-APPOKQHY.js:1:6498) at Object.onInvoke (_angular_core-17_3_3.js:31:6597) at Z.invoke (polyfills-APPOKQHY.js:1:6437) at Ne.run (polyfills-APPOKQHY.js:1:1821) at polyfills-APPOKQHY.js:2:566 at Z.invokeTask (polyfills-APPOKQHY.js:1:7123) at Object.onInvokeTask (_angular_core-17_3_3.js:31:6413)




handleError
@
_angular_core-17_3_3.js:5





next
@
_angular_core-17_3_3.js:32



r.next
@
rxjs-7_8_1.js:3



t._next
@
rxjs-7_8_1.js:3



t.next
@
rxjs-7_8_1.js:3



(anonymous)
@
rxjs-7_8_1.js:3



vr
@
rxjs-7_8_1.js:3



t.next
@
rxjs-7_8_1.js:3



emit
@
_angular_core-17_3_3.js:5



(anonymous)
@
_angular_core-17_3_3.js:31



invoke
@
polyfills-APPOKQHY.js:1



run
@
polyfills-APPOKQHY.js:1



runOutsideAngular
@
_angular_core-17_3_3.js:31



onHandleError
@
_angular_core-17_3_3.js:31



handleError
@
polyfills-APPOKQHY.js:1



runGuarded
@
polyfills-APPOKQHY.js:1



d.microtaskDrainDone
@
polyfills-APPOKQHY.js:1



I
@
polyfills-APPOKQHY.js:1



invokeTask
@
polyfills-APPOKQHY.js:1



J
@
polyfills-APPOKQHY.js:2



K
@
polyfills-APPOKQHY.js:2



ue
@
polyfills-APPOKQHY.js:2



If anyone has a valuable id to fix the issue I will appreciate it.
